# Is a topology determined by the convergence of nets?

Tags: general-topology, nets

Consider a space $X$ with two topologies $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$. It is easy to see that nets remain convergent if the topology is made coarser, i.e.

$$\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2 \quad  \Rightarrow \quad  \Big\{ x_\alpha \overset{\tau_2}{\longrightarrow} x \, \Rightarrow \, x_\alpha \overset{\tau_1}{\longrightarrow} x \Big\}.$$

My question is: does the converse hold? i.e. is it true that

$$\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2 \quad  \iff \quad  \Big\{ x_\alpha \overset{\tau_2}{\longrightarrow} x \, \Rightarrow \, x_\alpha \overset{\tau_1}{\longrightarrow} x \Big\}$$

? I think this is related to whether a topology is fully determined by the convergence of nets, but I couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: yes. the proof is trivial: suppose you have a net convergent in one of the topologies but not the other, now unwinding the definitions gives a set open in one but not the other

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think you are proving the forward implication, which is the one I understand...

Comment: What happens when you try to prove this?  Assume $\{ x_\alpha \overset{\tau_2}{\longrightarrow} x \, \Rightarrow \, x_\alpha \overset{\tau_1}{\longrightarrow} x \}
$.  Let $U \subset X$ be $\tau_1$-open.  Use the net characterization of "open" to deduce $U$ is $\tau_2$-open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to attempt an answer motivated by a comment by GEdgar.

I want to show that

$$ \Big\{ x_\alpha \overset{\tau_2}{\longrightarrow} x \, \Rightarrow \, x_\alpha \overset{\tau_1}{\longrightarrow} x \Big\} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2.$$

So consider $U \in \tau_1$. According to the theorem in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725201/a-characterization-of-open-sets-using-nets), this is equivalent to saying that

$$\forall x \in U \, \text{ and } \, \forall x_\alpha \overset{\tau_1}{\longrightarrow} x, \exists \beta \, \text{ such that } \, x_\alpha \in U,  \, \, \forall \alpha \geq \beta \, . $$

By assumption, the set of nets that $\tau_2$-converge to $x$ is included in the set of nets that $\tau_1$-converge to $x$. Thus the above statement also holds with $\tau_2$:

$$\forall x \in U \, \text{ and } \, \forall x_\alpha \overset{\tau_2}{\longrightarrow} x, \exists \beta \, \text{ such that } \, x_\alpha \in U,  \, \, \forall \alpha \geq \beta \, . $$

In conclusion, $U \in \tau_2$.

Is the argument correct?

Comment: Good.  Now, look at my hint, and see how you could have thought of that yourself.  Little steps like this help you become better at proof writing.