# Define $A:= \{f \in \Bbb R^{\Bbb R} \mid f \text{ injective} \} \subseteq \Bbb R^\Bbb R$. Determine wheter $A$ open or closed in $\Bbb R^\Bbb R$?

Tags: general-topology

> Define $A:= \{f \in \Bbb R^{\Bbb R} \mid f \text{ injective} \} \subseteq \Bbb R^\Bbb R$. Determine wheter $A$ open or closed in $\Bbb R^\Bbb R$ when $\Bbb R^\Bbb R$ has the product topology.

How can I make an educated guess on wheter $A$ should be open or closed? I don't think I have any tools at my disposal which I could use here. The complement of $A$ is the set of all maps $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ that aren't injective, but I have as little information about the complement as I do with $A$ so no help there either.

By the product topology $A$ is open in $\Bbb R^\Bbb R$ if $A$ is of the form $\prod_i U_i$ where $U_i \subset \Bbb R$ is open and $U_i = \Bbb R$ for all but finitely many $i$. Can I do something with this information?

Comment: Check your definition of product topology

Comment: @jjagmath Is there something wrong? I think that's the definition for open sets?

Comment: @AlvinL Yes it is. The set $\Bbb R^\Bbb R$ is the set of maps $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.

Comment: That's not the definition of the product topology.

Comment: $U_i = \Bbb R$ for all but finitely many $i$.

Comment: @PaulFrost That's right, but even with that correction, that's not the product topology.

Comment: I forgot "all but"... Added it.

Comment: The product topology is *induced* by those open sets you describe. However, there are open sets (maybe) not of the form you describe.

Comment: These are the basic open sets and I think I if I can show that $A$ is made up from these or is of that form it would suffice.

Comment: There will be points at which this set is open. I suggest you try to find points where it is not open, think about what needs to happen / not happen

Comment: Think what happens in $\Bbb R^2$, the product topology is the usual topology, but with your definition, you'll be saying that all of the open sets are of the form $U\times V$ with $U, V$ open in $\Bbb R$. How do you get an open disk as a product $U\times V$?

Comment: You don't, but for any point in an open disk you can find a product $U \times V$ that lies inside the disk and contains the point and vice versa.

Comment: JJag is just inviting you to edit your definition of the product topology, that's all

Comment: So don't write ”$A$ is open in $\Bbb R^\Bbb R$ if $A$ is of the form ...". Say that those open sets form a basis of the product topology, or something like that.

Comment: To get an answer that helps you you should explain what's your difficulty - *you don't need any tools* to answer this one!

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm fairly certain it is neither open nor closed. You might want to find a sequence of injective functions which tends to a constant and find an injective function which is also surjective (what does that mean?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that the product topology has more open sets than those of the form $\prod_{x \in \mathbb R} U_x$ where $U_x \subset \Bbb R$ is open and $U_x = \Bbb R$ for all but finitely many $x$. In fact, these sets form a *basis* for the product topology, so the open sets are all unions of such basic open sets.

The product topology is the *topology of pointwise convergence*. That is, a net $(f_\alpha)$ in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ converges to $f \in \mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ iff all nets $(f_\alpha(x))$ in $\mathbb R$ converge to $f(x) \in \mathbb R$.

1. $A$ is not closed.
   Let $f_n : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, f_n(x) = x/n$. These functions are injective, i.e. $(f_n)$ is a sequence in $A$. Clearly $f_n \to 0 \in \mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ pointwise. Since $0 \notin A$, we see that $A$ is not closed.
2. $A$ is not open.
   Let $f \in A$. If $A$ were open, there would be a basic open $\prod_x U_x$ such that $f \in \prod_x U_x \subset A$. Only finitely many $U_{x_i} \ne \mathbb R$, thus
   $$g  :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R, g(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & x \le  \max x_i \\ f( \max x_i) & x \ge  \max x_i\end{cases}$$
   is non-injective but contained in  $\prod_x U_x$. This is a contradiction.

**Update:**

As it is defined, $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ contains **all functions** $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. We can, however, consider the subset $C$ of all continuous functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. This subset inherits a topology from $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$. The above arguments show that $A_C = A \cap C$ is neither closed nor open in $C$. In fact, the functions $f_n$ and $0$ are in $C$, and if $f\in C$, then also $g \in C$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you elaborate a bit on how I can tie up the notion of convergence with the notion of open/closed sets in this case? It would seem that there is an if and only if condition for the openness of $A$?

Comment: @EmilGrönberg $A$ is closed if and only if it is closed with respect to taking limits of convergent nets of elements in $A$.

Comment: @EmilGrönberg See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1725201.

Comment: Thanks for the link. If you have the time could you still elaborate on the second point that $A$ is not open. I can follow up until the point when you state "thus ..." and define $g$  the way it is. What is the deal with the maximum function here? @PaulFrost

Comment: @EmilGrönberg The open set  $\prod_x U_x$ puts only very weak restrictions on its elements $g$. Only finitely many $U_{x_i} \ne \mathbb R$, thus $g(x)$ is **completely arbitrary** for $x \ne x_i$. Now I tried to define a non-injective $g$ such that $g(x_i) = f(x_i)$ for all $i$ wich assures that $f,g \in \prod_x U_x$ . There are **many** ways to do that, but taking a function $g$ which is constant for $x  > x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is an evident variant. This led me to define $g$ as above.

Answer (score 0):

Can think of $\mathbb R^\mathbb R$ as the product $\prod _{\alpha\in\mathbb R} \mathbb R$. So every map $f$ on $\mathbb R$ is identified with a family $(f(\alpha)) _{\alpha\in\mathbb R} \in \prod _{\alpha\in\mathbb R} \mathbb R$.

A basis in the product topology consists of subsets of the form $\prod _{\alpha\in\mathbb R} U_\alpha$, where $U_\alpha\in\tau _\mathbb R$ and $U_\alpha =\mathbb R$ for almost every $\alpha$.

$A$ is not open. Let $\prod U_\alpha\neq \emptyset$ be basic. There exist $\alpha_1\neq\alpha_2$ such that $U_{\alpha _i} = \mathbb R, \ i=1,2$. Take any $f \in \prod U_\alpha$ that satisfies $f(\alpha _1 ) = f(\alpha _2)$. So $A$ is unattainable as union of basic subsets.

$A^c$ is not open, either because any nonempty basic subset contains injective maps.

Let $U_{\alpha _i} \subset\mathbb R$ be nonempty proper open subsets for $i=1,\ldots, n$. If they are pairwise disjoint, fix any $f(\alpha _i) \in U_{\alpha _i}$ for all $i$. Otherwise pick different elements in case of intersection. Let the largest of the $f(\alpha _i)$ be $M$. Pick your favourite injective map whose values are $>M$ to populate the rest of the family.

E.g take $f(x) = e^x + M$ and then redefine $f(\alpha _i)$ to whatever you picked them to be.

Comment: The part that you claim is clear is most likely the part that they are having difficult with - they know the rest! Also, is it closed?!

Comment: @FShrike Neither open nor closed.