# Show that the map $c:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R, c(x)=1$ for all $x$ is in $\overline{A}$.

Tags: general-topology

> Consider $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ with the product topology. Let $A= \{\chi_F \mid F, F\text{ finite } \}$. Show that the map $c:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R, c(x)=1$ for all $x$ is in $\overline{A}$.

Let $\prod_{i} U_i$ be a basic open set containing $c$. If $A \cap \left(\prod_{i} U_i\right) \ne \emptyset$ the result follows.

I think I ought to use the fact that $\prod_{i} U_i$ consists of open sets $U_i$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and that $U_i \ne \Bbb R$ for only *finitely* many $i$, but I don't know how?

The finiteness condition certainly feels like it would be of use as I'm considering $\chi_F$ on finite $F$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic open set containing $c$ is of the form $\prod_i U_i$ with $U_i=\mathbb R$ for all $i$ not in a some finite set $F$ contained in $\mathbb R$. Now $\chi_F$ is in this neighborhood since it has the value $1$ on $F$. Hence, every neighborhood of $c$ intersects $A$.

More details: $\chi_F(i)=1$ whenever $i \in F$. $\prod_i U_i$ is precisely the set of functions $f$ such that $f(i) \in U_i$ for all $i$ and this will be true whenever  $f(i) \in U_i$ for $i \in F$. This is true for $f=\chi_f$ since $c \in \prod_i U_i$ which implies $1 \in U_i$ whenever $i \in F$.

Comment: You lost me at "Now $\chi_F$ is in this neighborhood since it has the value $1$ on $F$" why would this imply that $\chi_F \in \prod_i U_i$?

Comment: @SleepWalker $\chi_F(i)=1$ whenever $i \in F$. $\prod_i U_i$ is precisely the set of functions $f$ such that $f(i) \in U_i$ for all $i$ and this will be true whenever  $f(i) \in U_i$ for $i \in F$. This is true for $f=\chi_f$ since $c \in \prod_i U_i$ which implies $1 \in U_i$ whenever $i \in F$.

Comment: I see why I was confused. It seems that you're evaluating the maps $\chi_F$ and $f$ at $i$ whereas I am was thinking that $i$ is denoting an index of an arbitary indexing set.

Comment: I think I was able to show this by using the projections also. By definition $\bigcap_{x \in F} pr_x^{-1}(U_x)$ is a basis element for the product topology on $\Bbb R^\Bbb R$ so $c \in \bigcap_{x \in F} pr_x^{-1}(U_x) \iff c \in pr_x^{-1}(U_x) \iff pr_x(c) \in U_x \iff c(x) \in U_x \iff 1 \in U_x$ for all $x \in F \subset \Bbb R$. Thus $X_F \in \bigcap_{x \in F} pr_x^{-1}(U_x)$?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been perfectly answered by geetha290krm. My contribution is more an extended comment than another answer.

Your question seems to be related to [Define $A:= \{f \in \Bbb R^{\Bbb R} \mid f \text{ injective} \} \subseteq \Bbb R^\Bbb R$. Determine wheter $A$ open or closed in $\Bbb R^\Bbb R$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4498116) It is well-known that for any space $X$ and for any $M \subset X$, one has $f \in \overline M$ iff there exists a net $(f_\alpha)$ in $M$ such that $f_\alpha \to f$.

Here I want to illustrate that the function $c$ is the limit of a *net of functions* $\chi_F$ with finite carrier. Let $\Gamma$ be the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb R$ which is partially ordered by inclusion ($F \le  F$ iff $F \subset F'$). The set $\Gamma$ is directed: If $F, F' \in \Gamma$, then $F'' = F \cup F' \in \Gamma$ and $F, F' \le F''$. The net $(\chi_F)_{F \in \Gamma}$ converges to $c$: Consider any open neighborhood $V$ of $c$. There is a basic open neighborhood $U = \prod_{x \in \mathbb R}U_x$ such that $c \in U \subset  V$. We have $U_x = \mathbb R$ for all $x$ outside a finite $F^* \subset \mathbb F$. Thus for all $F \in \Gamma$ with $F^* \le F$ we have $\chi_F \in U$ since $c(x) = \chi_F(x)$ for all $x \in F^*$. This means $\chi_F \to c$.

Note that there is no *sequence* $(\chi_{F_n})$ in $A$ with $\chi_{F_n} \to c$. To see this, assume such a sequence exists. Let $F^* = \bigcup_n F_n$. This set is countable, thus there exists $\xi \in \mathbb R \setminus F^*$. The set $U = \prod_{x \in \mathbb R}U_x$ with $U_\xi = (0,2)$ and $U_x = \mathbb R$ for $x \ne \xi$ is an open neighborhood of $c$. But no $\chi_{F_n}$ is contained in $U$, thus $(\chi_{F_n)}$ does not converge to $c$, a contradiction.